# Variance definition (basics)

Tags: probability, variance, expected-value

> \begin{align}V(X)&=\sum_x(x-E(X))^2P(x)\tag{1}\\V(X)&=E([X-E(X)]^2)\tag{2}\\E(X)&=\sum_xxP(X=x)\tag{3}\end{align}

Can someone please explain me how I derive equation (2) from equation (1)? I would expect this to be based on equation (3), but in (3) both multipliers are x (i.e., x multiplied by P(x)), while in equation (1) there are different multipliers.

Thanks!

Comment: Equation 1 is  a direct definition from 2. Equation 2 is the definition of variance. You’re looking at variance of the variable X. So always multiply by P(x)

Comment: Thanks. Though still not fully clear. From (2) I can say that  my new random variable is [X-E(X)]^2. So, according to equation (3) in equation (1) I had to get P(x) as the probability of P([x-E(X)]^2). In other words, why I have  P(x) in equation 1.

Comment: I think the confusion might be arising from your equation notation. We can write Var(X) as the sum over i, of (x_i - E(X))^2 P(x_i), where E(X) is a number, and x_i is the value of each individual variable. We can then observe that Variance essentially takes the form of mean squared differences, which agrees with its definition. Hope this helps.

Comment: The idea is to observe the Variance as the mean of the squared difference of each “x” value from the expectation. It is incorrect to try and match variables here.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your help.